# Wordpress post in article alpahabetic ordering

Tags: wordpress, dictionary, indexing, alphabetical

Is there anyway or any plugin for in post listing a-z alphabeticly and when u click any alphabet it shows you the contents begining with that alpa. Most of plugins needs to add one by one every item that will be indexing which i dont want because i got a long list already. EXAMPLE:

A | ***B*** | C | D | E

BROS

BROTHER

BEGGIN

[Like in this picture but this plugin also wants items add one by one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLgvq.png)

Answer (score 0):

No plugin really needed: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67271/display-all-posts-starting-with-given-letter

The solution that may be use for you (example taken from the link above):

```
<ul class="posts">
     <?php 
     global $wpdb; 
     $request = "a" // could be any letter you want
     $results = $wpdb->get_results(
            "
            SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_title LIKE '$request%'
            AND post_type = 'post'
            AND post_status = 'publish'; 
            "
     ); 
     if ( $results ) 
     {
        foreach ( $results as $post ) 
        {
            setup_postdata ( $post ); 
            ?> 
            <li>
                ... loop stuff here (the_title, the_permalink) ... 
            </li>
            <?php 
        }
     } 
     else 
     {
        ?> 
        <div class="alert">No clubs found for that letter. Please try again, or use the search at the top.</div>
        <?php
     }
     ?>
</ul>
```

You could get your URLs with a $_GET[], so you can change the code above to this:

```
<ul class="posts">
<?php 
    global $wpdb;
    $request = 'a';
    if ( isset( $_GET[ "bl" ] ) ) {
        $request = sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ "bl" ] );
    }
     $results = $wpdb->get_results(
            "
            SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_title LIKE '$request%'
            AND post_type = 'post'
            AND post_status = 'publish'; 
            "
     ); 
     if ( $results ) 
     {
        foreach ( $results as $post ) 
        {
            setup_postdata ( $post ); 
            ?> 
            <li>
                //... loop stuff here (the_title, the_permalink) ... 
            </li>
            <?php 
        }
     } 
     else 
     {
        ?> 
        <div class="alert">No content found for that letter.</div>
        <?php
     }
     ?>
</ul>
```